# In the PayPal dialog, is there a way to specify whether to expand "Have PayPal Account" or "Don't have PayPal account"?

Tags: php, html, paypal

In PayPal's Web Payments Standard, when you click the button, for example `Buy Now`, PayPal dialog is shown with two options:

- `Have a PayPal Account?`
- `Don't have a PayPal Account?`

Is there a way to specify which one of those is "shown" (expanded) by default?

**EDIT:**

This is currently my form:

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="{SOMECODEHERE}">
        <input type="hidden" name="LANDINGPAGE" value="Billing">
        <table>
        <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Distance">Distance</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select> </td>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="PHP">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit">
        <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, however I only experience this in using PayPal Express Checkout. This refers to API parameter  `LANDINGPAGE` in **SetExpressCheckout** method:

> (Optional) Type of PayPal page to display. It is one of the following
>   values:
>
> - Billing – Non-PayPal account
> - Login – PayPal account login

[Reference API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the simple generated `Buy Now` button. I tried to add `<input type="hidden" name="LANDINGPAGE" value="Billing">` to the generated form with the `Buy Now` button :(

Comment: Hmm, I'm kind of lost. Care to give some other parameters you already set?

Comment: Ah, I see, thought you are using the NVP approach then via `curl()`. Based on this reference [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HF00TZS), there doesn't seem to be some parameter that serves like `LANDINGPAGE`. Wild attempt: set `LANDINGPAGE` to lowercase, :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can expand the section for users. You can, however,  add an email field to your form,  send it to PayPal,  and it will be entered in the login field for them.

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="user@example.com">
```